# Create an index without redundant code

Tags: sql-server, index, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I need a simple index creation script in a stored procedure as part of my database project.

- If the index in question already exists, I want to recreate it, to ensure that no other process has changed the index in question.
- I want to use `CREATE INDEX` with the `WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON)` option to recreate the existing index; so I can take advantage of the [performance benefits Microsoft mentions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql).
- If the index doesn't exist, I want to create it.
- Using `WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON)` when the index in question doesn't exist fails, so I cannot simply include that option without a check if the index exists or not.
- All that said, I do *not* want a solution that requires the command to create the index be repeated; that could result in maintenance issues (someone edits the first version of the command but not the second, and I get different indexes depending on whether it already existed or not).

Here is some sample code. Ideally, this would be the code needed; however, it fails if the index does *not* exist:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_a]
                ON [dbo].[animals]([BioNr] ASC)
                INCLUDE([ID], [Currency]) WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON);
```

This code works if the index doesn't exist, but doesn't replace the index if it *does* exist:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[animals]') AND name = N'IX_a')
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_a]
                ON [dbo].[animals]([BioNr] ASC)
                INCLUDE([ID], [Currency]);
```

This code works, but requires that the index creation code be in two places; that allows a future edit to break the intent of the script, resulting in a different index depending on whether it already existed or not:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[animals]') AND name = N'IX_a')
BEGIN
        CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_a]
                ON [dbo].[animals]([BioNr] ASC)
                INCLUDE([ID], [Currency])  WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON);      
END
ELSE
BEGIN
        CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_a]
                ON [dbo].[animals]([BioNr] ASC)
                INCLUDE([ID], [Currency]);      
END
```

Are there other options?

Comment: Are you only creating nonclustered indexes as part of this project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server 2016, this is very easy, you just need to make a choice between having simple scripts or enjoying whatever performance you've actually observed from `DROP_EXISTING` (is this quantifiable? Have you tested it?).

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.what(i int, INDEX x(i));
GO

DROP INDEX IF EXISTS dbo.what.x;
GO

CREATE INDEX x ON dbo.what(i DESC);
GO
```

Answer (score 4):

So, your requirements are:

- Create all indexes on the list, dropping and replacing existing indexes.
- If the index does exist, use `WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON)`.
- No repetition of the code to create the index.

I only see two options that would do this:

**Option 1: Dynamic SQL**

Build the basic `CREATE INDEX` command; then, if the index exists, tack on the `DROP_EXISTING` clause.

```
DECLARE @stmt NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @stmt = N'
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_a]
       ON [dbo].[animals]([BioNr] ASC)
       INCLUDE([ID], [Currency])'
+ CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[animals]') AND name = N'IX_a')
    THEN N' WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON)'
    ELSE N''
  END
+ N';'
;

EXECUTE sp_executesql @stmt;
```

Obviously, this solution has some issues of its own. In general, you have to maintain the statements as strings. The biggest issues here are that you have to remember to double any single quotes that should be in the statement. As the sample statement has none, this may not turn out to be an issue, but it must be noted. In particular, the statement must be altered if need other `WITH` options set. Again, in this example, that's not an issue. If all statements did have existing `WITH` options to include, it would be a huge issue either (though the statement would need tweaked:

```
SET @stmt = N'
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_a]
       ON [dbo].[animals]([BioNr] ASC)
       INCLUDE([ID], [Currency]) WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE'
+ CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[animals]') AND name = N'IX_a')
    THEN N', DROP_EXISTING = ON'
    ELSE N''
  END
+ N');'
;
```

**Option 2: create a "dummy" index**

Note that I wouldn't recommend this; it's actually at least as hard to maintain as simply having two copies of the `CREATE INDEX` statement, and causes extra work on the system. However, if you would expect that the index would almost always be there, it might be useful.

First, you create an index with the name you want (the columns don't matter); then, replace it with the index you actually want.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[animals]') AND name = N'IX_a')
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_a]
           ON [dbo].[animals] ([BioNr] ASC);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_a]
       ON [dbo].[animals]([BioNr] ASC)
       INCLUDE([ID], [Currency]) WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON);
```

As I said, I wouldn't recommend it, but it would (technically, at least) meet your requirements, so I thought I should mention it.

**Final Note**

It's probably worth posting a [`CONNECT`](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer) item, requesting that `DROP_EXISTING = ON` be allowed whether the index exists or not (if you can't find an existing one, at least). It seems entirely reasonable for the option to simply be ignored if the index doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have a simple approach to this; instead I wrote a "master" program [BuildIndexes]  which takes a table name and an index/statistic name term (default '%'), then for the table calls procedure [BuildIndexes_NameOfThisTable] which contains all the CREATE statements for indexes and statistics on t able [NameOfThisTable].  Well, likely to be table [B1_001].[dbo].[NameOfThisTable_01_2016], which is more worthwhile.

My program (which is currently private) finds and drops any matching-name indexes on the table first; an alternative for you would be to include a comment-type token /*wde*/ inside the index statement, which of course is contained in a string called using [sp_executesql], and if the index exists then - optionally - replace /*wde*/ with 'WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON)'.  In my case, a reason to not do that (maybe?) was that I might have decided to change the index definition, then run the procedure to apply the change.